# Typerror when using filter in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I added this filter to my angular app to remove certain strings from loaded data:

```
.filter('cleanteam', function () {
    return function (input) {
        return input.replace('AFC', '').replace('FC', '');
    }
});

 <h2 class="secondary-title">{{teamDetails.name |  cleanteam }}</h2>
```

You can see the error here:

http://alexanderlloyd.info/epl/#/teams/61

my controller looks a bit like this:

```
  .controller('teamController', function($scope, $routeParams, footballdataAPIservice) {
    $scope.id = $routeParams.id;
    $scope.team = [];
    $scope.teamDetails = [];
    //$scope.pageClass = '';



  $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(){
      $scope.loadedClass = 'page-team';
  });



    footballdataAPIservice.getTeam($scope.id).success(function (response) {
        $scope.team = response; 
    });

    footballdataAPIservice.getTeamDetails($scope.id).success(function (response) {
        $scope.teamDetails = response; 
    });

  })
```

Any reason why this might happen? Is it because `teamDetails.name` is not declared within an ng-repeat loop?

Comment: you filter should handle undefine condition before replacing inside filter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By looking at your code it seems that you didn't handle the case of undefined, while your `teamDetails.name` can be undefined `undefined` until it fetch data from service.

Because when you trying to fetch data form service through ajax, your input variable is undefined, when filter code tries to apply .replace method on undefined object, it will never work ( `.replace()` only works on string)

> Checking if your `teamDetails.name` object is defined or not is good
>   idea, because filter runs on every `digest` cycle.

**Filter**

```
.filter('cleanteam', function () {
    return function (input) {
      return angular.isDefined(input) && input != null ? //better error handling
             input.replace('AFC', '').replace('FC', ''):'';
    }
});
```

Hope this could help you, Thanks.

Comment: yeah true @pankajparkar it can happen that the template is rendered whilst no data are yet there and to my experience you have to handle it almost always. For more readable code you could use a typeof(input) === 'undefined' condition as well.

Comment: Thanks @bevada for suggestion, `angular.isDefined(input)` would be more angular way,

Comment: @bevada Do we need to check `input != null`? seems like `replace()` on null will never work

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like the filter is trying to execute before your async call has finished.

Try setting `teamDetails` to null when you initialize the controller and use an `ng-if` to prevent the DOM elements from loading before your data arrives:

```
$scope.id = $routeParams.id;
$scope.team = [];
$scope.teamDetails = null;

<h2 class="secondary-title" ng-if="teamDetails">{{teamDetails.name |  cleanteam }}</h2>
```

This will ensure that the filter won't execute before the async call has populated the `teamDetails` object.

More on `ng-if:` https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf